# convert from json to array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to get data to display in a table.  I don't know what I am doing wrong, but when I get the data from my page it is an array of single characters.  I could parse this myself but would prefer to know what I am doing wrong.

I have this php to get the data:

```
function BuildViewerCombo($autocomplete) {

    $wholeNumberCombo = array();
    $dbhandle = DB_Connect();       

    $result = QueryForward($dbhandle, SQL_WholeNumbersPartial($autocomplete));

    while($wholeNumber = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $wholeNumberCombo[] = array($wholeNumber['DocumentNbr'] => 'Number', $wholeNumber['DocumentRevision'] => 'Revision');
        }   


    //close the connection
    sqlsrv_close($dbhandle);

    return $wholeNumberCombo;
}
```

Which is called from this page

```
<?PHP 
    include "Scripts/DB_Functions.php5" ;
    include "Scripts/SQL_Viewer.php5" ;

    $wholeNumber = $_GET['wholeNumber'];
    echo json_encode(BuildViewerCombo($wholeNumber));
?>
```

Which gets loaded from this function

```
    function toggleDropdown()
    {           

        var wholeNumberData 


        var wholeNumber = document.getElementById('WholeNumber').value;

        if (wholeNumber != '') {
            wholeNumberData = GetData('wholeNumber', wholeNumber);

            var table = document.getElementById("wholeNumberDropdown");

            alert ('WN = ' + wholeNumberData.length);
            alert (wholeNumberData);
            for (var i in wholeNumberData) {
                alert(wholeNumberData[i]); 
            }

            }
        else {
            alert("Please enter a whole number.");
        }

    }
```

By calling this function:

```
function GetData(getType, param) {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("GET", 'ViewerWholeNumbers.php?wholeNumber=' + param, false);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    http.onload = function() {
    }
    http.send('wholeNumber=' + param);
    return http.responseText;
}
```

The data that gets returned is:

```
[{"SS3999":"Number","A":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","A":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","A":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","11":"Revision"},{"SS3999":"Number","A":"Revision"},
{"SS3999":"Number","":"Revision"}]
```

But `alert ('WN = ' + wholeNumberData.length);` returns 546 and when I try to loop through the array I get a single character for each element instead of the values.

Comment: you can use json_decode() function which is convert json to array

Comment: Yeah I agree, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Returned data is turned upside down. It should be {"Number":"SS3999"... and not the other way around

Comment: @Sel: json_decode is a php function and I need the data in javascript.

Comment: @drinovc: how does the data get upside down?  It did look funny to me but I thought that was how it worked.  I modified the function to     $wholeNumberCombo[] = array('Number' => $wholeNumber['DocumentNbr'], 'Revision' => $wholeNumber['DocumentRevision']);

Comment: You need `JSON.parse()` to parse the string and convert it to an array of objects in javascript.

Comment: @Joe: As imtheman said: It's flipped. Instead of {key: value} it's {value: key}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your associative array is flipped. You need to change

```
array($wholeNumber['DocumentNbr'] => 'Number', $wholeNumber['DocumentRevision'] => 'Revision');
```

to

```
array('Number' => $wholeNumber['DocumentNbr'], 'Revision' => $wholeNumber['DocumentRevision']);
```

You need that in order to access the elements of the JSON. Then, in your loop, you would use `wholeNumberData[i].Number` to get the number and `wholeNumberData[i].Revision` to get the revision.

**Update**:

As [@jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42139/jeroen) pointed out, you need `JSON.parse()` to convert the return string to JSON. In your `GetData` function replace your `return` with this:

```
return JSON.parse(http.responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks, I flipped it. However I get 'undefined' when trying to access a member like this: alert ('Number = ' + wholeNumberData[1].Number);